# Question got deleted by community while having a bounty on it

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, deletion

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268546/libgdx-for-android-draws-random-objects-after-reinitialize-of-game) a month ago. It had 2 downvotes, I edited my question. A week after the edit I placed a bounty to get some attention on the question.

Today I saw it got deleted by the Community user. I have not received any hint, the reputation from the bounty has gone too. What did I do wrong?

**Why get questions, which were edited after their downvotes, deleted by a script?** And that even while there is a bounty on it?

Comment: According to the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31268546/revisions) (the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31268546/timeline) is unavailable?), the bounty got added on Aug 28 at 9:27, while the question was deleted on  Aug 29 at 7:51. Edit: there was a comment asking whether OP was sure about the timing.

Comment: This seems to be an old [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970/245360) that was fixed. Maybe it is broken again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman do you have a other bug-report from that?

Comment: Regardless of the bug here, I've undeleted the question and refunded you the bounty (since it wasn't really fair that the system deleted the question the day-after you placed the bounty on it). Feel free to place the bounty again, if you do-so-wish.

Comment: @ine yours will do I think.

Comment: FWIW, I've also pinged Geoff [via a comment on the linked bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247970/prevent-questions-with-bounty-from-being-auto-deleted#comment861316_248063).

Comment: @CodeCaster: The timeline never recognizes deleted posts, even when asked about a deleted question. I find it irritating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A fix for this issue has been pushed.  There was yet another place where questions were deleted.  I have added the bounty check there to preserve these.  Thanks for the report.